# random voxel terrain on the gpu (dc vs. cms)

Tags: opengl, terrain, voxel

I want to create a random fractal terrain on the gpu (with a compute shader). I've started with implementing marching cubes: [Generating Complex Procedural Terrains Using the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch01.html), and it works really good: [marching cubes on the gpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOFPR.png). However, marching cubes can't extract sharp features or use an adaptive resolution.

So I looked for an advanced isosurface extraction algorithm and found [Dual Contouring of Hermite Data](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~taoju/research/dualContour.pdf). So I implemented dc in Java to test this algorithm and it looks great: [dc on the cpu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fqKJ.png). (There are some holes in the mesh and no sharp features, but I was too lazy to implement/fix this because it's only a prototype.)

But I've noticed some negative aspects:

- Intercell-dependent. (I have no idea how to port this to the gpu: the only resource I've found is [Dual Contouring with OpenCL](https://ngildea.blogspot.com/2015/06/dual-contouring-with-opencl.html).)
- I don't know how to create a chunk system, because there are no "clear" borders https://i.stack.imgur.com/62dy6.png.

So I continued my search for a better algorithm and found [Cubical Marching Squares: Adaptive Feature Preserving Surface Extraction from Volume Data](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cyy/publications/papers/Ho2005CMS.pdf). This seems to be the perfect algorithm for me: intercell-independent, adaptive, sharp features, primal structure and even manifold. Unfortunately, there are no resources on how to implement this algorithm except for this [Cubical Marching Squares Implementation](https://grassovsky.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/thesis1.pdf). I think I understand the two parts of the algorithm: create a grid, for each cell:

1. Subdivide until the maximum depth is reached or there is no need to do so.
2. Split each cell into 6 faces, extract their surface and stitch them together.

But I don't know how to connect those two parts (especially the part with transitional faces, page 38).

So does anybody know how to implement dc as a shader, how to implement cms or a better algorithm (maybe dual marching cubes, I think it has the same problem as dc, but I haven't tested it yet)?

Comment: awesome research, good question, did you find some more resources for it? i'll add a bounty on this if it helps you find the answer. cool topic i am interested to know more, if you know yourself and if others know as well.

Answer (score 2):

As you have already mentioned for the GPU you would need no intercell-dependencies... I'm sure people have come up with workarounds for that on DC but CMS should be one of the best for all those things that you need, namely intercell-independent (by definition), preserves sharp features, creates manifold geometry, and supports adaptive resolution.

In terms of resources on CMS I agree they are quite limited.

The original paper: http://graphics.csie.ntu.edu.tw/CMS/

This project by Matt Keeter has a 'C' CMS implementation in it (https://www.mattkeeter.com/projects/kokopelli/)
https://github.com/mkeeter/kokopelli  <-- code

I used Matt Keeter's implementation as a reference for my **partial** 'C++' implementation (the thesis that you linked), here is the code for it in case you didn't find it:
https://bitbucket.org/GRassovsky/cubical-marching-squares

However keep in mind that it is indeed partial, that is to say it has the main algorithm working (adaptive and manifold), but I haven't got around to implement the sharp-feature preservation, 2D and 3D disambiguation, etc. It is also currently a basic CPU implementation... I had the good intentions to implement all those things and make a GPU implementation but for now have had no time.

*"But I don't know how to connect those two parts"* - that only goes to say how badly I have written my thesis, because I try to explain how I do this :D (Mind you, I am not sure exactly how this was done in the original paper... should we say that some things are not very clear there and you would have to use your imagination :))